# Custom Post Type WP_Query with filters and search

Tags: wp-query, search, custom-post-type-archives

I have a custom post type called "doctor", this is the query I have set for displaying all the posts in the archive template:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'doctor',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => '12'
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

The Doctor CPT has two taxonomy's setup, Specialty and Locations. I also need to allow the users to filter the list of doctors by Specialty and/or Location and have a search box where they can type a name in and search for that name.

I installed Beautiful Taxonomy Filters, but when I select the Specialty or Location it doesn't change what loads on the page.

I'm looking for a solution that will show all doctors when they first go to the archive page, and the will have the option of narrowing down the list based on their selection.

Comment: If you are looking for filter's I would recommend using facetWP. I've been using this plugin for a while and it has never failed me. The only issue i've ran into were on my end AKA (not properly configuration). Once properly configured, they worked like a charm. https://facetwp.com/ 

It's either this or you could, you could use isotpe.js for custom filtering

Comment: So what is the problem, exactly? With some research on [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) arguments and taxonomy helper functions, this can be done quite easily. Have you tried anything, code-wise? If so, please show your efforts and tell us about the specific problems you are facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with:

```
$specialty_terms = get_terms('specialty');
$specialty_term_ids = wp_list_pluck($specialty_terms, 'slug');

$location_terms = get_terms('locations');
$location_term_ids = wp_list_pluck($location_terms, 'slug');

if( isset($_GET['docname']) ):
    $name_search = $_GET['docname'];
else:
    $name_search = "";
endif;

if( isset($_GET['specialty']) && $_GET['specialty'] !== ''):
    $specialty = $_GET['specialty'];
else:
    $specialty = $specialty_term_ids;
endif;

if( isset($_GET['location']) && $_GET['location'] !== ''):
    $location = $_GET['location'];
else:
    $location = $location_term_ids;
endif;


    $args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'doctor',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'paged'          => get_query_var('paged'),
    'posts_per_page' => '8',
    'post_title_like' => $name_search,
    'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'specialty',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $specialty
            ),
            array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'locations',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $location
            ))
        );
global $post;
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

There might be an easier way of doing this, but I created a text field where they can type a name and I also included two other select fields to select the Location and/or Specialty. I then pull the data in from the URL to modify the query.